# Is it necessary to filter the include path before autoloading?

Tags: php

is it necessary to filter the paths of files before autoloading them.

```
if (strpos ($class, '.') !== false || strpos ($class, '/') !== false
|| strpos ($class, '\\') !== false || strpos ($class, ':') !== false) {
    return 'error: contains bad character'; 
} else {
      if (file_exists ($class.'.php')) {
            require_once $class.'.php';
       }
}
```

Comment: "klasse" is german for "class" - i assume he translated the code before posting it for better understanding and forgot it at one place.

Comment: He should have posted an actual testcase, instead. Who knows what else he "forgot" to change between posting code and actually encountering the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that this is the contents of an autoloading function.  In that case, no it's not necessary to filter the path since the argument of an autoloading function is the class name that's being searched for.  PHP class names cannot contain any of those "bad characters."